# Try with resource how to call flush method

Tags: java, collections, try-catch, file-handling

Below code is used to write HotelReportModel  data into csv file. I am planning to replace try with try-with-resources Statement but how should i handle filewritter.flush?. which is inside finally block.

```
       FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(tempCSVFilePath);
        fileWriter.append(hotelReportModel.getHeader());
        fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);

        for(HotelReportModel imageStat:hotelReportModel.getContent()){
            fileWriter.append(imageStat.getMarketerName());
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(imageStat.getChainCode());
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(imageStat.getPropertyId());
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(imageStat.getContentProvider());
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(imageStat.getPropertyImageCount()));
            fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
        }
        LOGGER.info("CSV file was created successfully !!!");   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error in CsvFileWriter !!!",e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if(fileWriter != null) {
                fileWriter.flush();
                fileWriter.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while flushing/closing fileWriter !!!",e);
        }
    }
```

Is below try with resource is right?

```
         try(FileWriter fileWriter = = new FileWriter(tempCSVFilePath) ) {

        fileWriter.append(hotelReportModel.getHeader());
        fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);

        for(HotelReportModel imageStat:hotelReportModel.getContent()){
            fileWriter.append(imageStat.getMarketerName());
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(imageStat.getChainCode());
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(imageStat.getPropertyId());
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(imageStat.getContentProvider());
            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(imageStat.getPropertyImageCount()));
            fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
        }
        LOGGER.info("CSV file was created successfully !!!");   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error in CsvFileWriter !!!",e);
    } 
    }
```

Comment: `close` calls `flush` anyway, so you don't need to.

Comment: Jon u mean to say can i need to remove complete finally block right?

Comment: If you use try-with-resources, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to worry about that, as you're calling `close` (from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html())):

> Because the `BufferedReader` declared in a try-with-resource statement, it will be closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly.

(Their example used a `BufferedReader`, but that doesn't matter, as both `BufferedReader` and `FileWriter` implement `AutoCloseable`).

So simply using `try with resources` will both close and flush the `fileWriter`.